# Export of Java project fails

Tags: java, jar

I want to export my Java project as a runnable Jar but it keep gives me error like this:

```
    JAR creation failed. See details for additional information.
    Exported with compile warnings: FinalPhase/src/StopWordsAndStemmer.java
    Exported with compile warnings: FinalPhase/src/UpdateWktTable.java
    Exported with compile warnings: FinalPhase/src/ExtractLinks.java
    Exported with compile warnings: FinalPhase/src/Crawlers.java
    Exported with compile warnings: FinalPhase/src/CalculateWeightTable.java
    Exported with compile warnings: FinalPhase/src/FocusedCrawlingMain.java
    Exported with compile warnings: FinalPhase/src/CountWords.java
    Exported with compile warnings: FinalPhase/src/DealingWithIrrelevantPage.java
    Exported with compile warnings: FinalPhase/src/CalculateLinkScore.java
    Exported with compile warnings: FinalPhase/src/CreateNewIrrelevantTable.java
    Exported with compile warnings: FinalPhase/src/InsertNewList.java
    Exported with compile warnings: FinalPhase/src/CalculateRelevance.java
    Exported with compile warnings: FinalPhase/src/CalculateWeightPage.java
    Exported with compile warnings: FinalPhase/src/StringSplitter.java
    Exported with compile warnings: FinalPhase/src/View.java
    Exported with compile warnings: FinalPhase/src/DealingWithIrrelevantPages.java
    File not found: 
       C:\Users\Ramero Forester Carl\Documents\TA\FinalPhase\crawl.png.
    File not found:
       C:\Users\Ramero Forester Carl\Documents\TA\FinalPhase\resources\crawl.png.
```

I don't know why this happens.  Why can't I export my Java Project?

Comment: Please provide more details.  What exactly are you "exporting" from?  Exporting into?

Comment: I would start by investigating the File not found errors. That's usually not a good sign.

Comment: sorry. I export from java project into JAR file so that can be run when the JAR file double clicked

Comment: How the héll are you "exporting" the project? Eclipse? You need to tell us the details as we can't read minds. What about the files that are missing? Are they present?

Comment: what IDE are you using? How are you attempting to build the jar file?

Comment: 1) The *first* thing I'd look to resolve are those 'compile warnings'.  Compilation warnings are there for a reason.  Don't ignore them.  2) The very fact that `crawl.png` is referenced at **2 separate paths** tells me some logic is wrong.  Are there *supposed* to be 2 versions of the same image name in different paths?

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to delete the images. so there are two images but different path. after that I try to Export again it succeed but when I double clicked the JAR file It cannot open the application. but if I remove the imageIcon file from the application layout The JAR file exported succesfully and can be double clicked

Answer (score 1):

It usually happens when you are referring to files that are not present in the class path.
For me it had happened because my project contained any empty .java file.
It seems in your case crawl.png is not present.

Add it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be referring to some external file crawl.png. Add this file to your project.

Comment: try to provide valid path to the file,some times space between the words may not lead to valid path.

Comment: Its clearly saying its trying to access file from the file system.

Answer (score 0):

add crawl.png file to below path .it may resolve if u dont have any other errors.

```
C:\Users\Ramero Forester Carl   
\Documents\TA\FinalPhase\resources
```